# Storing c out value in string -jsp

Tags: jsp, foreach

How to store the value of `${cardlist.getCardname()}` in the `String cardname`:

```
<c:forEach items="${cardlist}" var="cardlist">
  <c:out value="${cardlist.getCardname()}"/>
  <c:out value="${cardlist.getCarddesc()}"/>
  <% String cardname = "???" %>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you still have trouble, please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mixing Scriptlets and JSTL/EL, you can use only the JSTL/EL like this:

```
<c:set var="cardname" value="${cardlist.getCardname()}" scope="page"></c:set>
```

This could be written without `get` but then lowercased first character:

```
<c:set var="cardname" value="${cardlist.cardname}" scope="page"></c:set>
```

If you need the `cardname` outside this jsp, you can change the scope.

Consider that this assignment is in a loop. Therefore after the loop the variale has the last value of the loop.